# custom address attribute with module: saving in admin and not in frontend

Tags: magento2

i developed a module to add two new fields in costumer address. The fields are showing but not saving in frontend checkout procedure. The fields are showing also in the admin area and there they saves correctly.
Now, i don't know how to  debug this.
How can i check where the problem is in the frontend?
Thank you.

EDIT

Ok, now i understand that my two custom attributes (codice_sdi and indirizzo_pec) are not saved in the shippingAddress javascript object. I've seen this using console.log.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Below is the best document for your requirement.

```
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html
```

Thanks

Comment: thank you, i think i need to understand JS mixin

Comment: ok i am trying but how can i debug if mixin is coded right?

Comment: i've edited the main post, news